# Hibernation in Windows 7 does not find the disk when resuming on RAID-0 Drive

Tags: windows-7, ssd, hibernate

I've been using hibernation on Windows 7 since I've have it, and it's been rock solid. Recently  I got a new laptop with a couple of SSDs in a RAID-0 configuration and have installed Windows 7 on it.

What I'm finding is that normal shutdown and restart are fine, however when I hibernate, the PC boots up and then reports that it can't find the disk.

It only happens on hibernation. If I hit `Ctrl-Alt-Del` again a couple of times it's fine.